# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: localStorage.setItem is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a project with localstorage, but when I save it with `setItem` error show up like this:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: localStorage.setItem is not a
> function

This is my code:

```
var dataPerson = {
    name: "Jhon",
    old: 20,
    family: "Doe",
};
console.log(dataPerson);

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(dataPerson));
} else {
    alert("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...");
}
```

I use jQuery v3.4.1, Thank you

Comment: From what scheme? `file://` `http://`? In a private tab? What browser? Have you enabled some security settings preventing tracking/storage of cookies? Do you use an extension that could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code again if you've redefined the localStorage on somewhere else.

The code is completely working.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jpzvta?embed=1&file=index.js

Answer (score 3):

Can you try invoking `localStorage` from the `window` object...

```js
window.localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(dataPerson));
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage:

> Exceptions
>
> SecurityError
> The request violates a policy decision, or the origin is not a valid scheme/host/port tuple (this can happen if the origin uses the
> file: or data: scheme, for example). For example, the user may have
> their browser configured to deny permission to persist data for the
> specified origin.

so you should envelope your code with a try-catch, that will solve your

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: localStorage.setItem is not a
> function

in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API you have an example of it, and given your particular exception, I'd start by

> Feature-detecting localStorage
>
> To be able to use localStorage, we should first verify that it is
> supported and available in the current browsing session.